# How can I use a viewmodel property in my GET action method without filling it in POST action method in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

I have these two lines in my GET action method:

```
var model = new CreateNKIphase1ViewModel();
model.SubjectTypeName = goalcard.SubjectType.Name;
```

I am doing this and using it for a IF statement in my view. Thats why I have this ViewModel property.
I dont want to fill my Model.SubjectTypeName in my POST action method. but when I debugg and try post my form I get following error and its pointed to my if Statement on Model.SubjecTypeName.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any type of solutions is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you expand your question? post some code from your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem before, and I solved it by redirect to another view in my post action.
Make your `Post` redirect to another view.

Answer (score 0):

An elegant way is to ignore this property from binding. Like below in your Post action method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save([Bind(Exclude= "SubjectTypeName")] CreateNKIphase1ViewModel model)
{
 ....
}
```